# Android proximity sensor sometimes behaves abnormally

Tags: android

Proximity sensor is used
Usually works well

However, sometimes the screen turns off when the object is close to the proximity sensor, and the screen turns on when the object is moved away from the proximity sensor.

Can you see why this is happening?

```
private class ProximityListener implements SensorEventListener {
        boolean proximity;

        private ProximityListener() {
            this.proximity = false;
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            if (event.values[0] == 0.0f) {
                this.proximity = true;
            } else {
                this.proximity = false;
            }
        }


        public void setProximity(boolean proximity)
        {
            this.proximity = proximity;
        }

        private boolean getProximity() {
            return this.proximity;
        }
    }

mProxLis = new ProximityListener();
mProxSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
mSensorManager.registerListener(mProxLis, mProxSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```